# Laravel routes auth

Tags: php, laravel, routes

```
if(Auth::attempt($credentials))
{
    return Redirect::to('admin');
}
```

**after that it drops me to a project.dev/**

**my route:**

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
 Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@getIndex');
});
```

**AdminController**

```
class AdminController extends \BaseController 
{ 

      public function getIndex() { 
            return View::make('admin.index'); 
      } 
}
```

views -> admin-> index.blade.php not loading

**Why i'm entering right email and password and after 'login' button it drops me again to login page? Error is somewhere in route**

**Master.blade.php**

```
<ul class="nav nav-list well">
        @if(Auth::user())
        <li class="nav-header">{{ ucwords(Auth::user()->loginname) }}</li>
        <li>{{ HTML::link('post', 'Add Post') }}</li>
        <li>{{ HTML::link('users', 'View Users') }}</li>
        <li>{{ HTML::link('logout', 'Logout') }}</li>
        @else
        <li>{{ HTML::link('login', 'Login') }}</li>
        @endif
    </ul>
```

this if auth not working...

p.s. I am very grateful for your trying to help me..

[my project is identical](https://github.com/fallendown/Laravel-4-login-registration), but i have different table name (not 'users'). Also he has a 4.0.5 version of Laravel, but I have 4.2.7 or something like that. Where can be mistake?

Comment: can you please try replacing `return Redirect::to('admin');` with `dd('success');` and see if you get success.

Comment: post relevant login code as well

Comment: please include the code for AdminController. I want to see code inside __construct method.. do you have Middleware in AdminController. This issue is likely from your middleware definition

Comment: <?php

class AdminController extends \BaseController {

 /**
  * Display a listing of the resource.
  *
  * @return Response
  */
 public function getIndex()
 {
  return View::make('admin.index');
  
 }

}

Comment: You need to include more detail in your question, don't paste it in comment but rather edit your question ad add them. Add for example your login form html code, the code for the controller that handle the login

Comment: can you show the code for your form? there is nothing wrong with Master.blade.php, Then show me all the codes you have inside AdminController

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if(Auth::attempt($credentials))
{
   return redirect()->intended('admin'); 
}
```